Finetuning on OpenAI: Validation Loss is Flatlining and below Training Loss?
Here is a screenshot of my training and validation loss

I'm new here - and I'm trying to fine tune an LLM for the first time via OpenAI.
I have created round about 100 examples, with the following format below. Plus I have another 40 in the same style which I use as my validation set.
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "You are an assistant that provides autonomy-supportive options."}, {"role": "user", "content": "How do I best organize my study schedule?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "Organizing your study schedule really depends on your goals and responsibilities. You might, for example, break your time into focused blocks with regular breaks or prioritize subjects based on difficulty to make the most impact. Is there a subject that you have more difficulty with than others? We could structure it around that. Alternatively, you could set daily goals to keep your approach flexible. Would you like to use time-blocking, prioritize by topic, or try a completely different approach? Also, which subjects feel most urgent to focus on first?"}]}

what's really been confusing me for the last couple of days:
No matter what I change with my hyperparamters (epoch, LR, batch size) - every single one of my graphs shows that the validation loss is significantly lower than my training loss. I do not understand why this is happening?
How can I address this? Or what causes it in the first place?
I have tried to artificially extend my dataset, but it didn't help. Also I have played around with every single combination of hyperparameters that I could think of.
